# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'users')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send users to different routes based on the roles of the user which is stored in the realtime firebase database, but I am getting the following error:

`App.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'users')`

Following is my App.js file where I am making the call for the firebase data"
App.js
`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import Landing from "./components/Landing";
import PhoneDetails from "./components/PhoneDetails";
import Home from "./components/Home/App.jsx";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";
import SignIn from "./components/Signin";

import { auth } from "./firebase-config.js";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import FirebaseData from "./firebaseData";

function App() {
  document.body.style = "background: #F8F5FA;";

  // getting the user data from firebase
  const firebaseData = FirebaseData();

  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = React.useState("");
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);
  const [role, setRole] = React.useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in
        // ...
        setIsAuthenticated(trEue);
        setDisplayName(user.displayName);

        // ERROR ON THIS LINE
        setRole(firebaseData.users[user.uid].role)

        // setRole(firebaseData.users[user.uid].role);
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setDisplayName("");
        setRole("");
      }
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("role:", role);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        element={
          <Home isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} displayName={displayName} role={role}/>
        }
      />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />

      {
        isAuthenticated && role === "admin" ? (
            <Route path="/home" element={<Landing />} />
        ) : (
            <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                    <Home isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} displayName={displayName} />
                }
            />
        )

      }
      

      {isAuthenticated && role === "admin" ? (
        <Route path="/details" element={<PhoneDetails />} />
      ) : (
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Home isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} displayName={displayName} />
          }
        />
      )}
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/" />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/" />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

In my App.js I am calling the FirebaseData() file which is given below:
firebaseData.js
`

```
import {database} from "./firebase-config";
import React from "react";
import {ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";
import {useEffect} from "react";

const db = database;

export default function FirebaseData() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        onValue(ref(db), (snapshot) => {
            setData(snapshot.val());
        });
    }, []);
    return data;

}
```

`

The data in the firebase DB is stored in the following format:
users
---->uid
------>roles

I've tried to find the solution for this but couldn't find any. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `firebaseData` is defined in the `useEffect` and check if users exists using `?` operator

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(firebaseData){
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    
       if (user) {
        // User is signed in
        // ...
        setIsAuthenticated(trEue);
        setDisplayName(user.displayName);

        // ERROR ON THIS LINE
        setRole(firebaseData.users?.[user.uid]?.role)

        // setRole(firebaseData.users[user.uid].role);
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setDisplayName("");
        setRole("");
      }
    });
   }
  }, [firebaseData]);
```